# Line separation / Line break in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to display 2 sets of data on the one list box, for example, I would wont to display the 7 times table and the 8 times table on the same listbox. Here is how I get the first set of data displaying:

```
            int awnser = 0;
        int z;
        z = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            awnser = z * i;

            listBox6.Items.Add(z + " * " + i + " = " + awnser.ToString());
        }
```

But how do I get a line break or separation so I can put the 8 times table just underneath?

Comment: If you want to make it pretty then use a ListView and use its support for Groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

**EDIT** Insert it *AFTER* your loop

```
        listBox6.Items.Add(z + " * " + i + " = " + awnser.ToString());
    } 

listBox6.Items.Add("--------------------");
```

Comment: it doesnt the first of both calculations then has the line break, i need all the 7 time tables, line break, then all the 8s, atm it gives me the 7x1 and 8x1 the line break, 7x2 and 8x2 the line break and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF this is easy to do using a custom template, but in WinForms I think you must do it by rendering the list items yourself.

Look at this example where they override the OnDrawItem method: http://www.syncfusion.com/FAQ/windowsforms/faq_c87c.aspx#q627q