# How to show multiple lines of text in Listbox in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

I have a listbox whose items contain only text. The listbox is having some fixed width. When I add a text which is having more width compare to the lisbox width, I am NOT able to see the remaining text.

Any solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

How about you remove the `Width` property?

that way the control will expand automatically - as wide as the maximum item

EDIT: Might not be a good idea, BUT:

You could nest the ListBox inside a Panel, and set the Panel's width to a constant value, while having Scrollbars enabled. that way - even if there's a line WIDER than the other lines - the user will be able to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WPF, add a text block and use it's text wrapping capabilities.

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
ListBoxItem li = new ListBoxItem();
TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock();
txtBlock.Width = 50;
txtBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
...
li.Content = txtBlock;
lb.Items.Add(li);
```

If not, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3667858/524475) for your question.

Comment: If you're using WPF, you should probably use DataTemplates anyway.